# Errors with java applet

Tags: java, applet, tic-tac-toe

I am receiving errors that I cannot fix. I get about 8 errors in these lines:

```
        if (weight [1] + weight[4] + weight[7] == twoWeights){
        if(weight[1]==0){
            return 1;

        else if (weight [4] == 0)
            return 4;

        else 
            return 7;

    }
    if (weight [2] + weight[5] + weight[8] == twoWeights){
        if(weight[2]==0)
            return 2;

        else if (weight [5] == 0)
            return 5;

        else 
            return 8;

    }
    if (weight [0] + weight[4] + weight[8] == twoWeights){
        if(weight[0]==0)
            return 0;

        else if (weight [4] == 0)
            return 4;

        else 
            return 8;

    }                       
    if (weight [2] + weight[4] + weight[6] == twoWeights){
        if(weight[2]==0)
            return 2;

        else if (weight [4] == 0)
            return 4;

        else 
            return 6;

    }                       
    return -1;
}

int getRandomSquare(){
    boolean gotEmptySquare = false;
    int selectedSquare = -1;

    do {
        selectedSquare = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
        if (squares[selectedSquare].getLabel().equals("")){
            gotEmptySquare = true;
        }
    }
    while (!gotEmptySquare);
        return selectedSquare;
    }
    void highlightWinner(int win1; int win2; int win3) {
        squares [win1].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        squares [win2].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        squares [win3].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    }
    void endTheGame (){
        newGameButton.setEnabled(true);
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            squares[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The errors are:

> TicTacToe.java:213: 'else' without 'if'           else if (weight [4] == 0)
>             ^
>
> TicTacToe.java:256: ';' expected  int getRandomSquare(){
>                        ^
>
> TicTacToe.java:269: illegal start of expression       void
>   highlightWinner(int win1; int win2; int win3) {       ^
>
> TicTacToe.java:269: ';' expected      void highlightWinner(int win1; int
>   win2; int win3) {
>                             ^
>
> TicTacToe.java:269: ';' expected      void highlightWinner(int win1; int
>   win2; int win3) {
>                                                          ^
>
> TicTacToe.java:274: illegal start of expression       void endTheGame (){
>         ^
>
> TicTacToe.java:274: ';' expected      void endTheGame (){
>                        ^

Comment: You have to read exception trace more attentive and you will be able to fix all problems.

Answer (score 2):

The second line in the above code has an extra `{`

Change `if(weight[1]==0){` to `if(weight[1]==0)`, since you are not closing the opening brace.
If you still see the errors after you make this change, please put up the whole class. I suspect you are not opening or closing the braces properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(weight[1]==0){
    return 1;

else if (weight [4] == 0)
    return 4;
```

You need to close the curly brace before you can start another if/else if. Or get rid of the opening brace if you only have one line after the if.